# which is the best face dataset for Deep Learning?

Tags: dataset, face

I'm a student who studies Deep learning. After learning some theories, I'm planning to make a model of facial image handling.
Anyway, I'm looking for a free facial dataset which is good to use. 
I found CUHK student image data and FERET dataset. 
I searched exactly same question to this one, but it seems too old (5 years ago).
So I'm renewing the question.

Do you guys have any recommendable facial dataset to use for free?
Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For faces exercises, I worked with CelebFaces Attributes Dataset (CelebA) dataset before. It contains over 200,000 celebrity images. It can be downloaded here:
- http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html

It is free for non-commercial research projects. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

For Dataset on Faces you can look into various dataset's [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwil6oPzlMHbAhWDsY8KHeikAwoQFghbMAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffacedetection.com%2Fdatasets%2F&usg=AOvVaw2xtYMGalhv5EerzvDUcpCm):